# Tu in opportunity as /tu/?

Tags: pronunciation

I heard some people pronounce tu in opportunity as /tu/ which I find a drastically un-unexpected way of pronunciation. Why is that?

update: don't get upset, the question is not about accent. It's about the phonology.

Comment: Which people?  Why would you find that surprising?  What would you suppose is the expected pronunciation - and why?  Have you looked a dictionary?  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opportunity  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/opportunity

Comment: Possibly you need to delete this question, because I think it will be downvoted to hell, as a simple Google search's first result gives you just that pronunciation, and though @JamesK 's link doesn't provide the phonetic description of this, but this other one does, if you can't listen to the voice sample: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/opportunity. You need to do your research. Regarding the question, if it is really unexpected from certain people and that interests you more, could you update what kind of people are they?

Comment: Your question boils down to "why I did not expect people to pronounce a word the way they did". Can you see why that isn't a suitable question for the site?

Comment: I'd guess this is about US v UK pronunciation (or other nations that use one or the other pronunciation) but it's pointless trying to answer until more details are provided. I'm sure there are already questions about pronunciation of long u as /u/ or /ju/ but not having much luck with the search function.

Comment: You should not use an em dash instead of a hyphen, especially since 'unexpected' does not need one anyway.

Comment: @StuartF - there are variations within the UK, e.g. northern English vs southern, Cockney vs RP, England vs Wales. Other words might be student stupor, stupid, stupendous, etc.

Comment: Anywhere between opur-toon-idi & oppa-chew-ni'i is just fine, depending on where you're from ;)

Comment: Please clarify your update.  What about the phonology is unexpected here?

Comment: @JamesK I believe the common pronunciation is more ergonomic and wonder how some people may opt for the /tu/ that in my viewpoint harder to pronounce and sound hard to ears. I don't blame does people, just wanted to know if there is any reasoning behind it. It may be just habitual.

Comment: There's no "ergonomic" difficulty in /tu/ compared to /tju/ or /tʃu/.  The choice of one or another is purely dialect and accent.  /tu/ is the common pronunciation in many American dialects.  I suspect that there is some kind of underlying misconception about how easy certain sound combinations are.

Comment: It's like people who say /tu/ for Toosday or /nu/ Noo York, whereas others will use /tju/ or /nju/ & my accent uses /tʃu/, as in chewsday. As my mother used to say, "It's just how you were brung up." ;)

Comment: @DoneWithThis. Good point, even Tuesday has evolved to pronounced smoother, why should you bother to pronounce it formally when it suffices to say toosday or choosday. Somehow "opportunity" went the opposite direction and some managed to pronounce it harder than easier!

Comment: There's no 'harder or easier' there's dialect. If you say Toosday you'll say opportoonity, if Chewsday, then opporchewnity.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. Thanks for your confidence in claiming the pronunciation cannot be hard or easy.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by that. Whatever dialect you grew up with is the 'easy' one; it's the one you use every day. The differences in pronunciation have nothing to do with one being hard or easy, they're entirely dialectical. Familiarity.

Answer (score 1):

The pronunciation of words often depends on the speaker's accent. There are many accents in English, and pronunciation of words can vary wildly depending on the speaker's country/region.

There's a phenomenon in some English accents called [yod dropping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-dropping) [this is a Wikipedia link].

The OED lists the American pronunciation as /ˌɑpərˈt(j)unədi/ - the (j) shown in brackets is the yod sound (like the y in you), and the brackets indicate that this is optional in some accents. Omitting this sound is an example of "yod dropping".  Note that not all Americans do this. Some pronounce it with the (j) sound, and some don't.

In the UK we tend not to do yod dropping in quite the same way, but there are some accents here which also have that feature.

The pronunciation in British English in the OED is given as /ˌɒpəˈtjuːnᵻti/ or /ˌɒpəˈtʃuːnᵻti/. In the latter note how the tju sound transforms into a tʃu sound (like the word chew).

Note that although the R is missing in the UK examples above, there are British accents which are rhotic, where the r is pronounced similar to the American pronunciation.